# jQuery unique temporary identifier Showing Randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an issue which I can not duplicate and am not sure why is is even causing it, so any help would be great.

I am grabbing text from a textarea like this in jQuery

```
var text = $(this).parent().find('textarea').val();
```

then putting the retrieved values into a string like this

```
var post_string = 'order_id=' + order_id + '&content_id=' + content_id + '&revision=' + text;
```

then sending it through an ajax request and 99.99% of the time it sends through properly, however 3 times out of over 20 thousand, the following text randomly gets added, sometimes in the middle and other times at the end (the numbers change)

```
jQuery17202261927353683859_1392326143805
```

First, what causes this in jQuery and has anyone ever seen this before. Second, does anyone know a way to guarantee this will not show up in a posted string?

Comment: I believe that the string is the name that jQuery assigns to a callback function for `jsonp` requests by default. Are you making any `jsonp` AJAX requests?

Comment: Im putting the ajax like this, so yea I guess:

`$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "posturl",
 data: post_string,
 dataType: 'json',
 
 success: function( response ){

 }
});`

Comment: you could try sending a data object instead of a plain string, makes more sense with a post request to me anyway and is easier to read.

Comment: That looks like the cache busting code.

Comment: j08691 do you mind elaborating on your comment? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried setting the cache option to false? Also, is there a problem with keeping it?